# Тире в простом предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Безусловно, данный пункт актуален для всех типов кранов –  как разборных, так и цельносварных.
Правильно ли я поставила тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать запятую: "Безусловно, данный пункт актуален для всех типов кранов, как разборных, так и цельносварных".

Постановка тире в подобных конструкциях факультативна и обычно не применяется, например:
"Компания «Хорс» осуществляет поставки насосов для перекачки всех типов жидкости, как простых так и сложных".

Тире - более сильный знак, чем запятая, и для его применения при союзной связи определений нет достаточных оснований. И относить информацию на второй план не имеет смысла, так как требуется расшифровка местоимения "всех".

Сравнить:

Безусловно, данный пункт актуален для всех типов кранов - разборных, цельносварных и т.д. (требуется распространенный  ряд при отсутствии союзов).

Мы долго шли по обочине дороги – бурой, ещё не высохшей от снега, сплошь покрытой прошлогодними листьями.